# Object not found!; Error 404

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

this is my code to connect my .php file to my databse:

```
$serverName="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="ichhya123";
$dbName="teacher";

$conn=mysqli_connect("$serverName","$username","$password","$dbName");
echo "Connected";
if(!$conn){
die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());}
```

however, when i try to run it using xampp in google chrome using 
    `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/teacher-login.php`, it gives me this error message:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.0

Comment: put `teacher-login.php` in `www` folder and run `http://localhost/teacher-login.php`.

Comment: The URL you use is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP cannot find your .php file.
Please check:

1. Your file should be here: xampp\htdocs\
2. File name (it should be: `teacher-login.php`)